# Visual C++ 2010: How do I tell the compiler that it requires a specific DLL?

Tags: dll, visual-c++-2010

As stated in the subject. I am a newbie at VC++/Visual Studio and can's seem to get this one issue right.

Answer (score 2):

## pragma comment (lib, "lib_name.lib")

That should do the trick.

There is probably some setting in the project properties too, but I can't check that right now.

Comment: Thanks (to (http://stackoverflow.com/users/349026/wajih), too). I don't have a .lib file available. I am writing a routine that accesses a function contained in a DLL provided by someone else. I need to resolve that function call at link time.

Comment: @Ralph: That's an entirely different question from the one you asked.  It's already been asked and answered, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393178/creating-an-msvc-import-library-from-a-dll-that-uses-stdcall

Comment: Thanks, @BenVoight. That will definitely be useful. Meanwhile, I seem to have solved the specific problem at runtime with a combination of LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I reference a DLL in a VC++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414761/how-do-i-reference-a-dll-in-a-vc-project)
Read through and you will get there. It is done using visual studio compiler settings.  You can do it via programming as well.  Check this [From SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903256/how-to-programmatically-check-c-dlls-and-c-sharp-dlls-for-references-to-debug)
 Shortcut via programming is to use the following

```
pragma comment (lib, "test.lib")
```

The library test.lib should be accessible to your program.

And finally look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85391/Microsoft-Visual-C-Static-and-Dynamic-Libraries) if you want to add third party libraries to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties -> Common Properties -> Frameworks and References

[image: MSVS2010 Screenshot]